# Download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I want to download csv files from "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=lomitapide&cntry1=&state1=&SearchAll=Search+all+studies&recrs=" website 
I am using python and selenium script as written below:But i get the exception "ElementNotInteractableException" and unable to download the page

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    fp=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
    browser.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=lomitapide&cntry1=&state1=&SearchAll=Search+all+studies&recrs=")
    browser.find_element_by_id("submit-download-list")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The element you referred as `find_element_by_id("submit-download-list")` actually downloads a `PDF` file. So for the benefit of future programmers and readers of this question/post/thread/discussion, you may consider to change your question header to **`Download and Save PDF file using selenium and python from popup`**

Here is the code block to Download and Save PDF file using selenium and python from popup:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
newpath = 'C:\\home\\DebanjanB'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",newpath)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,application/x-csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,application/pdf")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/plain,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,application/x-csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,application/pdf")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=lomitapide&cntry1=&state1=&SearchAll=Search+all+studies&recrs=")
browser.find_element_by_id("save-list-link").click()
download_link = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='submit-download-list']"))
)
download_link.click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is actually working!! and am able to download a PDF file. However I need a different result After clicking the download tab I want (i)csv or tsv file: from the drop down list I need to select tsv or csv format (ii)select number of studies to all 18 found studies (iii)select table columns to all available columns. Is it possible to add this modifications to the existing code. I would really appreciate if you could help me out....

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception ElementNotInteractableException because the element will be accessible after once the popup opens up. You are missing to click the download link which opens up the popup. please try the following,

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
browser.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=lomitapide&cntry1=&state1=&SearchAll=Search+all+studies&recrs=")
browser.find_element_by_id("save-list-link").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("submit-download-list")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However still the file is not being downloaded, though the pop up window is opening up now.