# Pop Up Window with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, window

I currently have a script that will log on to my company's wiki, visit a page, and select a download to pdf option available on the page. However, when this option is chosen, this dialogue box

[image: dialogue]

pops up asking me to tell Firefox what to do with it. I just need selenium to interact and hit the "ok" button.

I'm not sure how to inspect this window for elements, and am need of direction. Any documentation helps.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://company.wiki.com')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'user')
browser.fill('os_password', 'pass')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
browser.visit('https://pageoncompany.wiki.com')
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/ul/li[4]').click()
browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup)

Comment: Is this an alert or a popup window?  Either way you need to use the "SwitchTo()".  Let me know what it is and I'll be more than happy to help you further.

Comment: I believe it is a pop up since I tried to use driver.switch().alert().accept() and it didnt work

Comment: A few questions have been asked and answered here on SO. You can view them by googling for **selenium dialog box**.

Comment: Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox

Comment: This does not work. I set pdf's to automatically download, but the session created by splinter ignores the preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set the preferences through the web browser, then call my profile:

```
browser = Browser('firefox', profile=r'C:\Users\craab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0lot9hun.default')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set preferences in order to prevent coming of download popup ad download it to pre-defined folder.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)  # custom folder as set by repo
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", <download_folder_path>)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", content_type)
# Enable auto download, Avoid popup during downloads
fp.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", content_type)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Now is there a certain way I should call this to start the download, or will it work with my code as is?

Comment: @ChaseRaab You just need to click on download link, file will saved in mentioned download path.

Comment: The point of the script is that I won't have to click anything though.