# Avoid download pop up in python3 using serelinum Download pdf

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, download

**Object:**

automate following process.
1. Open particular web page, fill the information in search box, submit.
2. from search results click on first result and download the PDF

**Work done:**

To reach to this object I have written a code as first step. The code works fine but opens up download pop up. Till the time I can't get rid of it, I can not automate the process further. Searched for very many solutions. But none has worked.

For instance, [This](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html) solution is hard for me to understand and I think its more to do with Java then Python. I changed fire fox profile as suggested by many. [This](http://import%20selenium.webdriver%20as%20webdriver%20import%20selenium.webdriver.support.ui%20as%20ui%20from%20time%20import%20sleep%20import%20time%20import%20wget%20from%20wget%20import%20download%20import%20os%20#set%20firefox%20Profile%20profile%20=%20webdriver.FirefoxProfile()%20%20profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList',%202)%20profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting',%20False)%20profile.set_preference(%22browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete%22,%20False)%20profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir',%20os.getcwd())%20profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',%20'application/pdf')%20#set%20variable%20driver%20to%20open%20firefox%20driver%20=%20webdriver.Firefox(profile)%20#set%20variable%20webpage%20to%20open%20the%20expected%20URL%20webpage%20=%20r%22https://documents.un.org/prod/ods.nsf/home.xsp%22%20%20#%20edit%20me%20#set%20variable%20to%20enter%20in%20search%20box%20%20searchterm%20=%20%22A/HRC/41/23%22%20%20#%20edit%20me%20%20#open%20the%20webpage%20with%20get%20command%20driver.get(webpage)%20%20#find%20the%20element%20%22symbol%22,%20insert%20data%20and%20click%20submit.%20symbolBox%20=%20driver.find_element_by_id(%22view:_id1:_id2:txtSymbol%22)%20symbolBox.send_keys(searchterm)%20submit%20=%20driver.find_element_by_id(%22view:_id1:_id2:btnRefine%22)%20submit.click()%20#list%20of%20search%20results%20open%20up%20and%201st%20occarance%20is%20clicked%20by%20coppying%20its%20id%20element%20downloadPage%20=%20driver.find_element_by_id(%22view:_id1:_id2:cbMain:_id135:rptResults:0:linkURL%22)%20downloadPage.click()%20#change%20windiows.%20with%20sleep%20time%20window_before%20=%20driver.window_handles[0]%20window_after%20=%20driver.window_handles[1]%20%20time.sleep(10)%20%20driver.switch_to.window(window_after)%20%20#the%20actual%20download%20of%20the%20pdf%20page%20theDownload%20=%20driver.find_element_by_id(%22download%22)%20%20theDownload.click()) dose matches though not exactly same. I haven't tried as there is no much difference. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45609181/3604513) speaks about changing fire fox profile but that doesn't work.

My code is as below

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from time import sleep
import time
import wget
from wget import download
import os
#set firefox Profile
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
#set variable driver to open firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
#set variable webpage to open the expected URL
webpage = r"https://documents.un.org/prod/ods.nsf/home.xsp"  # edit me
#set variable to enter in search box

searchterm = "A/HRC/41/23"  # edit me

#open the webpage with get command
driver.get(webpage)

#find the element "symbol", insert data and click submit.
symbolBox = driver.find_element_by_id("view:_id1:_id2:txtSymbol")
symbolBox.send_keys(searchterm)
submit = driver.find_element_by_id("view:_id1:_id2:btnRefine")
submit.click()
#list of search results open up and 1st occarance is clicked by coppying its id element
downloadPage = driver.find_element_by_id("view:_id1:_id2:cbMain:_id135:rptResults:0:linkURL")
downloadPage.click()
#change windiows. with sleep time
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]

time.sleep(10)

driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

#the actual download of the pdf page
theDownload = driver.find_element_by_id("download")

theDownload.click()
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

The "Selections" popup is not a different window/tab, it's just an HTML popup. You can tell this because if you right click on the dialog, you will see the normal context menu. You just need to make your "Language" and "File type(s)" selections and click the "Download selected" button.

Comment: You have code that gets window handles, e.g. `window_before`. The dialog that pops up is not a new window (in browser terms), it's just an HTML dialog. You can treat it like all the other HTML on the page. I'm assuming that's what you are calling the "download pop up" that you can't handle... at least that's what I see when I follow your code manually on the site.

Comment: Agree. It's HTML dialogue from OS. The problem is, this box appears asking me whether to save the pdf file or to open it. I want to skip this box and save the file directly