# python : disable download popup when using firefox with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, firefox

I have script that using selenium and firefox to automating download action. 
The problem is whenever I run script I always get pop up from firefox keep asking what kinds of action I would like to do, even though I set download path in firefox preference. I checked files and folders to create master mimeTypes.rdf for all users, but I couldn't find mine.(I'm using ubuntu). I found ~/.mozilla/firefox but there was no file for directory of my profile name nor any file has an extension like .rdf

here is the criminal's pic that making me crazy

[firefox download popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B01NH.jpg)

below is what I've done to disable the popup.

```
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", 'application/zip')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/zip')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/i-06/Downloads")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent many hours trying to suppress that "save or open" pop-up that appears when downloading a file using the firefox driver with selenium (python 3.x). None of the many suggestions involving various values for     `profile.set_preference` worked for me. Maybe I missed something.

Still, I finally got it working by the other method that is recommended : using an existing firefox profile.

You can tweak your default (or custom) profile to the file save behaviour you want. Type the following in the firefox address bar and make changes here :

```
about:preferences#applications
```

Then the only setting up you need to do to download the file into your current working directory is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(<your firefox profile directory>)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

If you have a typical ubuntu setup, you can find your default firefox profile dir by viewing *~/.mozilla/firefox/profile.ini*

In that .ini file, look for Path under [Profile0]

Comment: sorry but I didn't get the "(<your firefox profile directory>)" part exactly. What is expected the address of directory in quotes or [profile0]? In my case I cann't see anything as [Profile0]

Comment: @sangharsh : Could you print your profiles.ini file here?

Comment: sure I will. Give me some time

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you need to define both. Remove the below line from your code

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", 'application/zip')
```

Also sometime the MIME type of zip file can be different based on the server. It could be any of below

- application/octet-stream
- multipart/x-zip
- application/zip
- application/zip-compressed
- application/x-zip-compressed

So in Network tab check what is the content type you are getting and add that to your profile to make sure the dialog doesn't come

Answer (score 0):

I removed `profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", 'application/zip')` as Tarun Lalwani suggest and it still work. But my problem was that I put `application/mp4` instead of `video/mp4`. You could check [MIME](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_de_m%C3%A9dias) type [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).