# Selenium Webdriver not Finding Download Link

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code where I am trying to navigate my company website, scrape some data and click a download link for each person in a list. I am getting errors here when I try and click the download link (it's a link that automatically downloads the file once clicked).

Any ideas why this isnt working? The error I'm getting just acts as if nothing was found. Code posted below as well as code from website

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", 
{"download.default_directory": downloads,
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing.enabled": True,
"safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": True})

driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)

gameIds = []
for p in people:
    driver.get(base_url + p)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 0.01).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="resumeContainer"]/ul/li/div/div[2]/label'))).click()
    gameIds.extend(gameIds_temp)

print(gameIds)
```

```
<div _ngcontent-isj-c5="" class="col-md-8 resume-name-container"><label _ngcontent-isj-c5="" class="resume-name pointer" digitaldata-resume="cs Resume_2019.doc>Profile Page">CS Resume_2019.doc</label><!----><p _ngcontent-isj-c5="" class="resumemodified mb-0">Last updated <b _ngcontent-isj-c5=""><!----> 11 months ago
</b></p></div>
<label _ngcontent-isj-c5="" class="resume-name pointer" digitaldata-resume="cs Resume_2019.doc>Profile Page">cs Resume_2019.doc</label>
```

```
C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\scraper.py:120: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\scraper.py", line 157, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 0.01).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="resumeContainer"]/ul/li/div/div[2]/label'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: This is not really a self contained example.
Which browser are you using?
You probably did not set a download dir and disable the download prompt

Comment: Using Chrome - not sure what you mean by the rest... could you clarify?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645648/python-disable-download-popup-when-using-firefox-with-selenium this is for firefox but there are similar commands for chrome

Comment: The id resumeContainer is no where in your html snippet, how should the locator work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", 
{"download.default_directory": <your_path>,
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing.enabled": True,
"safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": True})

driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Updated with the error I'm getting and new code - it fails at the .click() line