# Python Selenium: Download files through filling forms

Tags: python, selenium, autofill

I've to download xml files from webage (https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower), wherein I've to click hyperlinks which produce a form to be filled and submitted to begin the download. I've created the code with selenium webdriver. The code gets executed until the point of accessing the webpage and clicking on the xml hyperlink, but ceases to perform the rest of the functions (clicking radio and check boxes, filling text and clicking the submit button) to complete the download. Kindly let me know if I'm missing out on any functions in my code which may be resulting this issue. Any suggestion / help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DatG_Py_Dat")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="xml (Open in a new window)"]').click()

class FormPage(object):

 def fill_form(self, data):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "radio" and @value = "Non-commercial"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "checkbox" and @value = "R&D"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
    return self


@staticmethod
def submit(self):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "submit" and @value = "Submit"]').click()
                data = {
                    'name_d': 'abc',
                    'mail_d': 'xyz@gmail.com',
                }
                FormPage().fill_form(data).submit(self)
                driver.quit()
```

Comment: You have bunch of errors here. Starting with indentation... Your `submit()` should be part of `FormPage()` class if I got this right... You are also calling the class itself within `submit()`, but are you calling the class at all in your script (otherwise `fill_form()` and `submit()` won't be triggered ever)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup)