# What is wrong with this selenium firefox profile to download file into customized folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium and python v3.6 to automate firefox to download file into a customized folder. The location of the folder is `C:/Users/username/Dropbox/Inv/`.

Below is my firefox profile.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:/Users/username/Dropbox/Inv/')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'text/plain')
```

Currently, the file is always downloaded in the default folder `C:\Users\username\Downloads`. How do I get the downloaded folder location to be `C:/Users/username/Dropbox/Inv/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The problem lies with the string specifying the download directory. I should use `\\` and not `/`.

```
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:\\Users\\username\\Dropbox\\Inv')
```

The code has been verified to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `profile` while launching Firefox:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
```

Check [8.4. How to auto save files using custom Firefox profile ?](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile) in Selenium Docs FAQ.

This is the example in the link:

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium")
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("selenium-2").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I do not have enough points to upvote.