# Error while accessing a file in a path using openpyxl python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using **openpyxl** module in python to access a file in a path. But my file path looks like below and it is on network drive

> "\\rsc.secad.com\hdrive\shared\test.xlsx"

To escape '\\' backslashes in above path I have added \ to it ,as shown in below code.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
fp = "\\\rsc.secad.com\\hdrive\\shared\\test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(fp)
```

And when I ran the program, I got following error.

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:"\\\rsc.secad.com\\hdrive\\shared\\test.xlsx"
```

Is there any way to access the path with double backslashes in it using openpyxl ?

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths?

Comment: @3NiGMa No, I didn't try it. I have no idea about it. can it be implemented along openpyxl ?

Comment: can you move the python script into the same directory (folder) as the excel file, then change `fp` to `test.xlsx`?

Comment: @3NiGMa the given path is a network location/drive . Where as my python interpreter is on local drive. We are trying run it using command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could simply use the forward slash instead like this

```
fp = "//rsc.secad.com/hdrive/shared/test.xlsx"
```

Comment: was thinking this, although in what situation would forward slashes work and not double backslashes?

Comment: Answer is right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805462/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-specifying-folder-location-in-p