# Selenium unable to fetch the select results

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium and trying to get the values of the select tag from a site (link in code), but whenever I try to get the select tag it returns an empty field.

My Code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://lifeinsurance.adityabirlacapital.com/about-us/public-disclosure'
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select-public-year"))

print([option.text for option in select.options])
# Output: ['']
```

When I looked at the page source it shows me the following:

```html
<select Name="selectPublicYear" class="demo-default select selectized selectPublicYear" id="select-public-year" name="SelectedYear">
  <option value="2020-2021">2020-2021</option>
  <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020</option>
  <option value="2018-2019">2018-2019</option>
  <option value="2017-2018">2017-2018</option>
  <option value="2016-2017">2016-2017</option>
  <option value="2015-2016">2015-2016</option>
  <option value="2014-2015">2014-2015</option>
  <option value="2013-2014">2013-2014</option>
  <option value="2012-2013">2012-2013</option>
  <option value="2011-2012">2011-2012</option>
  <option value="2010-2011">2010-2011</option>
  <option value="2009-2010">2009-2010</option>
  <option value="2008-2009">2008-2009</option>
  <option value="2007-2008">2007-2008</option>
  <option value="2006-2007">2006-2007</option>
  <option value="2005-2006">2005-2006</option>
</select>
```

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably those options are not loaded to DOM unless you expand the list. So try to all clicking that select to expand it and then fetch the options again.

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: `select.click()`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'click'` It gave the following error

Comment: Try something like first `driver.find_element_by_id("select-public-year").click()` and then `select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select-public-year"))`

Comment: `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)` It gave this error, for `driver.find_element_by_id("select-public-year").click()`

Comment: The page may be using bootstrap or something similar so what the user will be interactive with is another set of web elements altogether. That `select` would be hidden if so.

Comment: How can I perform the desired action if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<select>` tag is having the attribute `style="display: none;"` so that's not your desired element.

---

To extract the texts e.g. *2020-2021*, from all of the `<class="option">` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://lifeinsurance.adityabirlacapital.com/about-us/public-disclosure')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.selectize-input.items.full.has-options.has-items"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.selectize-dropdown-content div.option")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://lifeinsurance.adityabirlacapital.com/about-us/public-disclosure')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='selectize-input items full has-options has-items']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']//div[contains(@class, 'option')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['2020-2021', '2019-2020', '2018-2019', '2017-2018', '2016-2017', '2015-2016', '2014-2015', '2013-2014', '2012-2013', '2011-2012', '2010-2011', '2009-2010', '2008-2009', '2007-2008', '2006-2007', '2005-2006']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks and worked like a charm. I wanted to know now if I wish to select a year and a quarter and see the results of the selection and then download all the files that are shown. Can you share some references on how should I go about it?

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar A lot would depend on how the elements to download all the files are defined. If they are static, you can click in a loop. But if they contains `__doposback` you have tweak the clicking strategy a bit.

Comment: Could you please refer me to some good materials on static download approach.

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup/45098422#45098422) discussion.

Comment: How can I get the values of the quarter section after the year now

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar Sounds like a different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems synchronization issue. I would suggest use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"select-public-year"))))

print([option.text for option in select.options])
```

You need to import below library

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

Snapshot tested using java since I don't have python in working machine.

[image]

Comment: `TimeoutException: Message:` It gave the following error

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar : You may some other issue similar code I have run with java and its working perfectly. Please see the attachment.

Comment: Please have a look at the link I have created a colab notebook: [Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NO7zmrQeVTxwlZyfXASsgBiuAskdmfk4?usp=sharing)